# Displaying "Task" in a particular table cell depending on status. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I ran into a problem where I need to output my task objects into a table.
I have created status columns (New, To do, In progress etc), but I have no idea how do I output my tasks into a particular table cell depending on its status and if there are going to be two task objects with the same status then for another one I would like to create a separate row so they won't both be inside the same cell.

Unfortunately, I cannot provide any code example since I've tried it so many ways and none of them worked. Here is how I do it now, but it doesn't work as I need.

```
            <div className="taskboard">
            <table className="table" id={'board_'+this.amount}>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th className="0">Story</th>
                        <th className="1">New</th>
                        <th className="2">To do</th>
                        <th className="3">Pending</th>
                        <th className="4">In progress</th>
                        <th className="5">Internal Review</th>
                        <th className="6">Customer Review</th>
                        <th className="7">Done</th>
                        <th className="8">Reject</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        {this.tasks.map((task, i) => <td key={i}><Task task={task}/></td>)}
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this? the idea is that for each task you create a `<tr/>`, then inside of it you decide whether or not to display a `<Task />` inside of a `<td />` based on the Status of the task (new, pending, etc).

```js
< div className = "taskboard" > 
  <table className="table" id={'board_' + this.amount}>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th className="0">Story</th>
        <th className="1">New</th>
        <th className="2">To do</th>
        <th className="3">Pending</th>
        <th className="4">In progress</th>
        <th className="5">Internal Review</th>
        <th className="6">Customer Review</th>
        <th className="7">Done</th>
        <th className="8">Reject</th>
      </tr>
      
      {this.tasks.map((task, i) => 
        <tr>
          // maybe here insert some cells that are common for all task states. like name, date, etc.
          // then choose which state to put the task into:
          <td>
            { task.status === "New" &&
              <Task task={task}/>
            }
          </td>
          <td>
            { task.status === "Pending" &&
               <Task task={task}/> 
            }
          </td>
          // more <td />
        </tr>
      )
      }
      
    </tbody>
  </table> 
< /div>
```

eventually you can refactor the whole `<tr />` into a new component that receives a task object and displays a row with the relevant cells

Comment: I was cracking my head trying to do this for 2 days! You saved my life! Big thanx!

Answer (score 1):

This can also be rendered with a little div - css styling as well.

Here is a working fiddle on ReactJS.
Hope this helps.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Celinton/du4ez33L/4/)

```
var data = {
  "new_item": ['Story 10', 'Story 11'],
  "to_do": ['Story 1', 'Story 5'],
  "pending": ['Story 2', 'Story 3', 'Story 7'],
  "in_progress": ['Story 4', 'Story 6', 'Story 8', 'Story 9']
};
var Container = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div className='divTableBody'>
      < StatusColumn name = 'New'
      id = 'new_item' ></StatusColumn>< StatusColumn name = 'To Do'
    id = 'to_do' > < /StatusColumn> < StatusColumn name = 'Pending'
    id = 'pending' > < /StatusColumn> < StatusColumn name = 'In Progress'
    id = 'in_progress' > < /StatusColumn> < /div > ;
  }
});

var StatusColumn = React.createClass({
      render() {
      var _this = this;
        var items = [];
        for( var item in data){
                  data[item].map(function(x) {
                  if(item === _this.props.id)
                      items.push(<div className='divTableCell'>{x}</div>);
                      })


        }

          return <div className='divTableRow'> 
          <div className='divTableHeading'>{this.props.name}</div>
          <div>{items}</div>
           < /div>
        }
      });

    ReactDOM.render( < Container / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thanx for this one as well. I might be needing this when I will implement dnd functionality